# !contains on Notes field

Tags: rally

My app has keywords boxes to provide words to filter on containing or not containing and it does it in a number of fields on the objects (defects, user stories and tasks) such as Notes and Description.

We just realized that if we specify a nonsense word in the exclude box it returns fewer results than if we did not specify the word. I believe it should be true that if we specify a word that does not exist anywhere in the search results, it should be exactly the same results if we did not specify this search criteria.

I narrowed it down to only the Notes field. The rest of the queries return the expected results.

(Notes !contains "illidan")

This is how I am using it. I am testing on the web services api page, so I've completely removed my app from the equation. If I search defects with only that query, I get 4512 results. If I just run an empty query I get 16526 results. But my test word is not contained anywhere in defects, confirmed by searching (Notes contains "illidan") which returns 0 results.

Is there something I'm missing here or is this a bug in Rally?

Comment: I know nothing at all about Rally, but is this a null issue? Do the excluded items have anything unusual in their Notes fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon's comment is on-target. Testing on a much smaller dataset, what I see is that !contains works as follows:

(Notes !contains "illidan")

Will return all Defects where the Notes field is *non-empty*  AND does not contain "Illidan". Thus if you have:

- N Defects
- EN Defects with an Empty Notes field
- Zero Defects with Notes fields that contain the string "illidan"

Your query will return (N - EN) Defects.

This is not documented in Rally's query help system, adding to the confusion. However, it is expected behavior in terms of how the query logic functions.

I'll file an enhancement request with Rally's documentation team to better document this behavior.

Comment: BTW to add the "EN" Defects back in to your results set, i.e. those whose Notes field is empty and therefore does not contain the string of concern. you can use `(Notes = "")` to find them.